# wordpress jquery error Property '$'

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm getting the following error when using the simple code within wordpress. any idea how to solve this problem?

**error:**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function 
(anonymous function) 
x.event.dispatch
v.handle
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery('#room_type').change(function(){
        var location = $(this).val(),
            div = $('#' + location);
        jQuery('div').hide();
        div.show();
});
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<select id="room_type">
    <option value="">-- Type --</option>
    <option value="oneroom">One room</option>
    <option value="tworoom">Two room</option>
</select>

<div id="oneroom" style="display:none">
    CONTENT 1
</div>
<div id="tworoom" style="display:none">
    CONTENT 2
</div>
```

Comment: Right here in the documentation: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your functions and jQuery code in this:

```
;(function ($) {

    //Code in here

})(jQuery);
```

This assigns the `$` to jQuery only. Doing this prevents conflicts with other libraries/code that also use the `$`. Also leading this code with a `;` protects your function from unclosed scripts. I wouldn't rely on the `noConflict()` method.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
;(function ($) {
    $('#room_type').change(function(){
        var location = $(this).val(),
            div = $('#' + location);
        $('div').hide();
        div.show();
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jonnysooter/KyajU/1/)**

For you other problem, try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
;(function ($) {
    $('#room_type').change(function(){
        var location = $(this).val(),
            div = $('#' + location);
        $("div[id$='room']").hide();
        div.show();
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: the page when blank when selecting an option from the drop down

Comment: @acctman doesn't sound like a related problem. Your code, once fixed, hides all divs on teh page which of course makes your page go away.

Comment: @KevinB I removed other jquery code from the page and it still does the blank page on select

Comment: @acctman This will cause your page to appear blank: `jQuery('div').hide();` it selects all divs and hides them.

Comment: @acctman I don't know what to tell you. I built a fiddle and your code works just fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/jonnysooter/KyajU/

Comment: @JonnySooter here is an example of whats happening `nemx.me/avant/floorplans/`

Comment: @acctman try the code from my latest edit and it should work.

Comment: is there a way to make all selections display as a default?

Comment: This question has been answered. If you need additional help, you should open another question.

Answer (score 3):

That is because `$` is not defined in your code (`jQuery.noConflict` was probably used somewhere)

Just use `jQuery` as your jQuery variable

Answer (score 2):

`jQuery.noConflict` was probably called, so you won't be able to use the shorthand `$` without first setting up an alias.

This is often done with:

```
(function ($) {//jQuery is now stored as the `$` parameter in this function
    ...code here...
}(jQuery));
```

Alternatively, for document.ready you can use the aliasing shorthand:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
   //this code will execute on DOM ready and the `$` parameter will be set
    ...code here...
});
```

Alternatively, stop using `$(...)` as a function, and replace it with the more verbose `jQuery(...)`:

```
jQuery('#room_type').change(function(){
    var location = jQuery(this).val(),
        div = jQuery('#' + location);
    jQuery('div').hide();
    div.show();
});
```

Comment: the page is being refreshed to a blank window every time I select an option from the drop down. no error in the console window

Comment: @acctman, that would be because you are hiding every div on the page with `jQuery('div').hide()`.

Comment: how do i target just id="oneroom" and id="tworoom"

Comment: @acctman, I recommend googling that question first, and if you can't find an answer, to then move on to asking a question on [SO]. [That question is so laughably easy to answer, that it concerns me that you're not able to find the answer on your own](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/).

Answer (score 1):

Do what Jonny Sooter said, or change any `$` to `jQuery` like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery('#room_type').change(function(){
    var location = jQuery(this).val(),
        div = jQuery('#' + location);
    jQuery('div').hide();
    div.show();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery('#room_type').change(function(){
        var location = $(this).val(),
            div = $('#' + location);
        jQuery('div').hide();
        div.show();
});
</script>
```

change this to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery('#room_type').change(function(){
        var location = jQuery(this).val(),
            div = jQuery('#' + location);
        jQuery('div').hide();
        div.show();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Need to do it to the `$(this)` line too.

Comment: thanks Kevin, I missed that